# What shall we do about the survey tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have the following

[survey-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey-sampling) with 161 questions and a wiki

[survey-weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey-weights) with 138 qs, a wiki

[survey](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey) 974 qs, no wiki

[polling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) 45 qs, no wiki

[voting-system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-system) 21 qs, wiki

It seems to me that voting-systems is quite distinct but the others offer scope for rationalisation. I shall post two answers with proposals to attract comments.

This follows on from some discussion in a post in the current tag synonym thread.

Comment: This approach appears problematic because you are asking multiple questions and your answers address different questions altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that [survey-weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey-weights) is really a proper subset of [survey-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey-sampling) and so could be made a synonym of it. Survey sampling as it is usually understood generates weights to be used in the subsequent analysis.

Comment: The wikis make it clear that the weighting is related to a special kind of survey designing, indicating it would be erroneous to make them synonyms.  The implication "is a proper subset" => "should be synonymous" is erroneous.  Consistent application of it would reduce all tags to a common parent, "statistics or machine learning"! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinct meaning for polling as most people would use this either for opinion polls or for the action of taking part in an election (although I am not sure if that is used in all anglophone jurisdictions). The concept of survey is much broader. Nonetheless I think [polling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) could well be made a synonym of [survey](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey)